# Remove UserControls from occuping space in ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, web-controls

I have a kind of Admin and Member page. Both share the same page. The only difference is Admin sees one UserControl more apart from the Member. Currently I am doing this:

```
ucControl.Visible = false;
```

for Members. This works. But it is very inefficient. It queries database and follows the normal lifecycle and it does occupy space in ViewState. How do I get of this and make it more efficient so it doesn't query the database and doesn't occupy space in ViewState unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Make

```
EnableViewState = "false"
```

for this controls.
I'd also disable this controls, except of making them invisible.

Comment: That doesn't stop the usercontrol's lifecycle. Does it? It will still execute and query my database.

Comment: I see a method named Dispose in UserControl. If I call it the lifecycle stops and also doesn't occupy space in ViewState. However, I am not sure of it's implications.

Comment: yes, this removes them from viewstate, but once you disable it, it also removes queries.

Comment: Disposing object isn't the best way, cause there are a lot of internal stuff. Just try to disable them on paren OnLoad event.

Comment: I really don't know what you mean by the term ***disable***. There isn't any disable property or method in usercontrol.

Comment: Really =) it goes like this myDropDownList.Enabled = false;

Comment: You do not mean I should go individual in each of my controls and set them Enabled = false;. Do you? :)

Comment: Sorry, but haven't you said that admin page has one control more. Why don't you just set this control either enabled and visible, this is one time change.

Comment: Sorry but you need to read the question again. I didn't say it has one control more. I said "The only difference is Admin sees one UserControl more apart from the Member".

Comment: So you want to disable viewstate for other controls, except one that is visible to admin?

Answer (score 0):

Just add code to the UserControl that only queries the db etc if it is visible.

You might want to set `ucControl.Visible` in the Init phase - presumably you know by this stage if the user is a Member or an Admin.  Then you can simply test for visibility in the UserControl's Page_Load.

In answer to the comment:

> yes I am setting it in Init phase and check for visibility. Do I also disable viewstate there in page_load itself? if I find the user is member?

If the user is member (i.e. the control is not visible), then don't do anything.  In this way the UserControl won't contribute to ViewState:

```
// inside the UserControl's Page_Load method
if (this.Visible)
{
    // The user is an Admin, do whatever is needed (access database, databind, ...)
    ...
}
else
{
    // The user is a Member, this UserControl is not used, do nothing.
}
```

Comment: yes I am setting it in Init phase and check for visibility. Do I also disable viewstate there in page_load itself? if I find the user is member?

Answer (score 0):

Use a placeholder and load the control in dynamically - the only trouble with this is if you need to use postbacks and remember data then its starts to get a little bit tricky.

Comment: I know which is why I didn't go with that approach and I still won't ;)